# Fixing Route 53 CNAME Alias slow reponse times with Cloudfront

Tags: performance, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have just setup a CloudFront distribution in order to speed up my website's images. My images are stored on S3. I have setup a custom subdomain in Route53 using a CNAME alias to my CloudFront distribution endpoint.

However, I have found the following when testing speeds with a sample image:

- 418ms Avg Load Time for https://s3.amazonaws.com/deseouserimages/make+a+wish.jpg
- 97ms Avg Load Time for https://cdn.lodeseo.com/make+a+wish.jpg
- 57ms Avg Load Time for https://d3fi09n8kfe0h5.cloudfront.net/make+a+wish.jpg

These 3 URLs point to the same image:

- First URL is original image from S3
- Second URL is image from CloudFront distribution when accesing via a CNAME Alias set up in Route53
- Third URL is image directly from Cloudfront distribution

Tests were done using Pingdom from Dallas location. I have reached similar results from other locations.

The slower load times from S3 make perfect sense. The image is not being cached at edge locations. However, almost double the load time just by using a CNAME in front of the distribution seems way too slow.
I would prefer using the CNAME but not at this performance cost.

Am I missing something here? I had read everywhere that the extra DNS CNAME lookup would be negligible in most situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CNAME delay should disappear into the noise once the result of looking up the CNAME and its target are cached by any given resolver, but unless it's a CNAME that doesn't span multiple domains (e.g. `foo.example.com. CNAME bar.example.com.`) the double lookup time is always going to be inevitable.

However, you don't need a CNAME for Route 53 to point to a CloudFront distribution.  You can use an A record alias, which us an internal feature of Route 53 so that the lookup is done internal to Route 53 rather than by the external referral of a CNAME.  The delay then goes away, because Route 53 supplies the answer from its internal databases.

Edit your existing RR in the Route 53 console... change it from CNAME to A, then set Alias to Yes.  Then select the CloudFront distribution from the alias target selection list and save the record.

Comment: If you use another DNS than Route 53, instead of doing a CNAME you can use the more efficient is to setup a subdomain delegation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/creating-migrating.html. You create your zone in Route 53 and use the A record ALIAS. Then you add an NS record to delegate your subdomain to AWS.

Comment: The thing with ALIASes to CloudFront distributions is their TTL is 60s (and CF distribution records themselves too). That is not very optimal as basically caching is minimal. In our case the DNS resolving time is the biggest part of a HTTPS request to CloudFront.

Comment: @NikolayDimitrov that's true, but it's something of a classic tradeoff -- the low TTL is part of the resiliency strategy.  The nature of the integration isn't publicly documented but CloudFront and Route 53 are tightly coupled, so that queries for each assigned hostname in `*.cloudfront.net` (as well as any aliases pointing to it) can receive a customized answer based not only on the location of the viewer but also on what the system knows about the current state of the CloudFront edge network. When using a CNAME, the target of the CNAME still has a low TTL, so your concern is still present.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I understand. I am just hopeful some day AWS can do the resilience part using "fixed" (or longer lived) IPs rather than relying on DNS load-balancing.

Comment: @NikolayDimitrov and Michael-sqlbot, guys. I have exactly 60s TTL issue on alias to Load Balancer, I think all aliases is like that. That is extra 300ms on every 1min even though my closest region is 50ms latency away. Any idea to reduce the first time resolution? Is it possible to change Route 53 default authoritative nameserver to a closer one?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html#request-routing